# Ascii immediate in gas?

Tags: assembly, x86, ascii, gnu-assembler, character-literals

Is there a way to enter in a character as an immediate in `gas`? For example:

```
mov $1,     %rax # decimal
mov $0xA,   %rbx # hex
mov $0b100, %rcx # binary

mov 'A', %rdx # something like this?
```

I know I can define this in the `.ascii` or `.string` directive but can this be done inline as an immediate?

Comment: @Peter Cordes -- ok, it looks like your comment on that question answers the question. I just need to add the $: `mov $'A', %rdx` and it works.